# Para cada resultado, uma nova linha no php

Tags: php, html, sql

Eu tenho um banco de dados onde na tabela users possuo as colunas:

```
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| imp_cod1 | imp_local1 | imp_cod2 | imp_local2 | imp_cod3 | imp_local3 |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
|       13 | RECEPÇÃO   |          |            |       18 | CEO        |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
```

Note que os valores da `imp2` estão todos vazios, pois neste caso, somente `imp1` está com dados.
No meu código html eu uso o seguinte formato para exibir as informações da imp1:

```
 <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Impressora</th>
                <th>Modelo</th>
                <th>Contagem</th>
                <th>Situação</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><?php echo $imp_cod1; ?></th>
                <td><b><?php echo $imp_local1; ?></b></td>
                <td><?php echo $imp_modelo1; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $imp_contador1; ?></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-round btn-success"><?php echo $imp_situacao1; ?></button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Hoje, quando eu tenho um segundo dado na `imp2`, `imp3`... eu vou manualmente e crio um novo campo de resultados como o exemplo acima citou `<tr>`

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de eu tornar isso automático de modo que eu não precise ficar editando o PHP toda vez que eu inserir ou deletar novos dados na tabela.

Código de conexão com a db (toda página que requer que o usuário esteja logado tem um include pra esta página): http://pastebin.com/02WJFzEp

Código da minha página onde estou com dificuldades para incluir novas linhas de forma automática: http://pastebin.com/GcTbPn3H (na linha 251 tem o primeiro preenchimento de dados, ele acaba na 257. 
Logo abaixo tem mais 7 preenchimentos onde eu já deixei prontos.)

Agora suponhamos que o usuário só possui a `imp1` e todas as outras estão vazias, mesmo assim meu sistema buscará todas as outra e deixará em branco, e por o código html já estar criado, ele deixa as linhas criadas mas em branco também. Gostaria de saber se consigo fazer isso se tornar automático, na teoria: se o campo da imp estiver vazio não criar linha, caso contrario criar linha e preencher dados...

Se eu estiver indo por um caminho errado na lógica estou apto a mudar, sou iniciante e estava com urgência no término disto.

Segue foto de como o sistema fica mesmo com dados em branco:

[image: Dados em branco]

Comment: Você quer poder ter imp_cod4, imp_cod5, imp_cod6, etc ou você quer colocar mais linhas, tipo 
linha1: |imp_cod1|imp_local1|imp_cod2|imp_local2|imp_cod3|imp_local3|
linha2: |imp_cod1|imp_local1|imp_cod2|imp_local2|imp_cod3|imp_local3|
e assim por diante?

Comment: Na verdade eu já tenho criado os imp_ até o 8 pois este é o máximo de que eu preciso.
O que eu preciso é que algum script "cheque" se tem algum valor dentro dos imp e se houver ele criar uma nova linha no html.

Comment: Vamos lá : 1-"Nota que os valores das imp2 e imp3 estão todos vazios", ao meu ver `imp_local3` não está vazio, mas é só um detalhe. 2- Pode colocar o código que busca esses dados, o código acima da tabela ? 3-"quando eu tenho um segundo dado na imp2, imp3... eu vou manualmente e crio um novo campo" você se refere a criar uma nova linha da tabela html ?

Comment: 1 - desculpe pela minha observação, realmente o imp3 está com dados.
2 - o código completo devo postá-lo aqui mesmo ou em outro lugar externo?
3 - exatamente isso, eu sempre vou lá e crio uma nova linha no html onde eu insiro manualmente uma "extração" do banco de dados echo $imp_cod2.

Comment: está usando pdo?

Comment: Nâo tem `while` ou `foreach` nesse código?

Comment: 2-Pode editar sua questão e colocar o faltante...

Comment: A questão é que isso não é um banco de dados, No máximo, um array... O correto era ter uma tabela com campos: código, local, modelo, contador e cada linha da tabela representaria uma impressora. Desta forma, poderia ter 8, 80 ou 8000 impressoras, uma por linha, como uma planilha. Na logica que aparenta usar, só mesmo mexendo no código a cada mudança. Dai não precisa de codigo php, faz em html mesmo que sai mais barato.

Comment: Bom dia pessoal, editei a pergunta com os códigos que uso.
Obrigado pelo retorno

Answer (score 2):

É perceptível que seu código peca pela [normalização de dados](http://www.luis.blog.br/normalizacao-de-dados-e-as-formas-normais.aspx).

Apesar de o seu problema não ser a repetição de dados entre registros, você acaba criando colunas repetidas, o que é praticamente impossível de ter a manutenção apenas por código PHP (sempre existe uma gambiarra que resolve). O seu problema é corrigido pela [1FN](http://www.luis.blog.br/primeira-forma-normal-1fn-normalizacao-de-dados.aspx)

Basicamente você possui um relacionamento 1.* (one-to-many ou um-para-muitos). Sendo o seu registro único o `user` e o registro relacionado o `imp`.

Como diagrama, podemos definir o relacionamento como (utilizarei apenas os campos necessários):

[image: Relacionamento entre user e imp - agregação]

Esse relacionamento, do tipo agregação, permite que você possua um número infinito de locais para associar ao usuário.

Outro caso, pode ocorrer caso você possua uma lista definida e limitada de locais. Nesse caso, o relacionamento irá mudar e será considerada uma associação simples:

[image: Relacionamento entre user e imp - associação simples]

Basicamente, o relacionamento acima é para quando você possui, por exemplo, uma lista de impressoras. E essas impressoras podem ser compartilhadas entre os usuários, mas não podem existir impressoras além das que foram previamente cadastradas na tabela `imp`.

A título de curiosidade, existe um outro caso, que é uma extensão do segundo exemplo, é quando você possui uma quantidade definida de itens (10 impressoras), mas, as impressoras não podem ser compartilhadas. Quem "obter" a impressora terá reservado ela e será acessível somente para o usuário vinculado.

Nesse último caso, basta adicionar a coluna `imp_id` da tabela `user_has_imp` como uma `unique key`. Dessa forma, uma impressora não poderá ser compartilhada entre usuários e continuará com a possibilidade de um usuário ter mais de uma impressora.

Indiferente a abordagem escolhida, ambos lhe darão a possibilidade e flexibilidade de quantas associações criar.

Para questão de código, basta retornar a associação:

```
//prepared statement da PDO
$query = 'SELECT * FROM imp WHERE user_id = :userid';
```

ou

```
//prepared statement da PDO
$query = 'SELECT * FROM imp WHERE id IN (SELECT imp_id FROM user_has_imp WHERE user_id = :userid)';
```

Com o retorno dos dados, basta realizar o loop pelo resultado:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM imp WHERE user_id = :userid');
$statement->bindValue(':userid' , $userId);
$statement->execute();

foreach($statement->fetch() as $row)
{
    var_dump($row);
}
```

> Agora suponhamos que o usuário só possui a imp1 e todas as outras estão vazias, mesmo assim meu sistema buscara todas as outra e deixará em branco, e por o código html já estar criado, ele deixa as linhas criadas mas em branco também. Gostaria de saber se consigo fazer isso se tornar automático, na teoria: se o campo da imp estiver vazio não criar linha, caso contrario criar linha e preencher dados...

Bastaria utilizar a lógica do `foreach`, acima apresentado, para criar o HTML. Somente será criado para os resultados que existirem.

PS.: Todos os códigos são apenas exemplos.

PS. 2: nomes criados pelo MySQLWorkBench.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo retorno Gabriel!
Estou ciente de que meu código está pecando bastante na organização...
Você sugere que eu crie uma nova Tabela onde nela eu aponte as imp com o id do usuário a quem ela pertence?
Pelo que entendi, desta maneira ficaria mais fácil de lidar com o código.

Comment: Exatamente. Esse seria o primeiro exemplo, aonde você pode ter quantas imp você quiser para um usuário sem limitações de quantidade.

Comment: Entendi.
Na verdade eu estou usando o script nesse formato porque sou inexperiente no assunto e como o restante já estava tudo criado, achei que seria mais fácil manter assim, tendo em vista que não ainda não sei utilizar o comando JOIN para "ligar" as imp de uma tabela separada com o seu respectivo usuário.
Seria pedir muito um exemplo na prática de como fazer isto? Ou você acha que devo estudar mais sob o assunto antes de querer aplica-lo?
Novamente te agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Com os exemplos dados, você nem precisa usar JOIN, apenas percorrer as consultas e ir aninhando uma a uma. Sobre joins, teria que formular outra pergunta e/ou estudar. Olhe neste link, uma explicação minha sobre joins, é bem básico: http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/469816-como-utilizar-o-comando-union/?p=1864034